# Yii2 REST api conditional call to relational class

Tags: angularjs, rest, yii2, relationship

it's my first post here, so apologies if I transgress any rules.

Here I am, setting up an angular application based on a RESTful Yii2 API.
So, I have a little problem that I cannot seems to solve. 
I have 3 classes: event, user, and participation. A user can participate to 0,n event. 
So in my "view" action of the user controller in my api, I have to return a JSON formatted user object like the following:

```
[{
"user_id":5,
"userGroup_id":1,
"user_login":"demo",
"participations":
    [
    {"event":{event_id:1,event_name:"test"},
     "user_id":5,
     "Droit_id":30
     },
    {"event":{event_id:2,event_name:"test2"},
     "user_id":5,
     "Droit_id":10
     }
    ]
 }]
```

On the other hand, when i'm in the event contoller, I'd like to do the opposite:

```
[{
"event_id":1,
"event_name":"test",
"participations":
[{
    "event_id": 1,      
    "user":{user_id:5,user_login:"demo"},
    "Droit_id":30
},
{
    "event_id": 5,  
    "user":{user_id:6,user_login:"demo2"},
    "Droit_id":10
}]
```

}]

So I could setup my "participation" model so it would return the user and the event each time, with the "fields()" function, but I don't want to.
I want the model "participation" to have a field "user" when called from a "event" and vice-versa, not both at the same time ( I don't need the event to be returned when I'm already in the event ).

I use `"use yii\rest\Controller;"` and 
       `$behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ];`
to make every output JSON formatted.

Here's my view action:

```
$query = User::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->with('participations');
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

This output

```
[{
"user_id":5,
"userGroup_id":1,
"user_login":"demo",
"participations":
    [
    {"event_id":1,"user_id":5,"Droit_id":30},
    {"event_id":2,"user_id":5,"Droit_id":10}
    ]
}]
```

I tried "with('participations.event');" but doesn't work.
My relations are all correctly set up

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Relation in Participation Model as

```
    public function getEvent(){
    return $this->hasOne(Event::className(),['id' => 'eventId']);
    }
```

Now Your Changed Query as

```
   $query = User::find()
            ->where(['user_id' => $id])
            ->with(['participations' => function($query){

                $query->with('event');

            }]);

        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
```

Comment: It returns me an error:
 PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Ok, now the error is gone.
However, when i reached the controller, I added "&expand=participations" to get the participations. If I don't put that in my request's url, the participations aren't linked. 
What should I use in "expand" to link the event to the participation?
I tried 
"&expand=participations,participations.event", "&expand=participations,participation.event"
"&expand=participations,event"
None of the above works...

Comment: When I return the $query directly, nothing change from the original one though...